# DISTINCT values for 4 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a table like this  :

```
maiL_client   platform   rendering_engine   category

Android         mobile     Webkit           read
Android         mobile     Webkit           deleted
Apple iPhone    mobile     Webkit           skimmed
Other           Other      desktop          read
Other           Other      desktop          deleted
Android         Other      mobile           skimmed
```

Now what I need is to get the distinct values for all of these columns. Is it possible to get it in one query ? If I use simple SELECT DISTINCT column_names then it will geive duplicate values. I am using this in CodeIgniter active record pattern.

Comment: what result do you expect if you would just have first to lines? do you want to see them both? because category is different or you just want to see one?

Comment: what do you expect to return? one column of all those distinct values from all those 4 columns?

Comment: If so just do `SELECT DISTINCT mail_client FROM table` then `UNION` with `SELECT DISTINCT platform FROM table` then `UNION` with the other two columns as well

Comment: What I need to get is mail_client with unique values platform with unique values etc. It has to be under different column names and then only I can take the value out for further use. I don't know this is possible here. The thing is that I have a lot many columns and so it is practically not possible to take distinct with seperate queries.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'mail_client' AS `key`,mail_client as `value` FROM table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT 'platform', platform FROM table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT'rendering_engine', rendering_engine FROM table
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT'category', category FROM table
```

or try the below, and then split or explode the result as it'll return a comma separated list

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Mail_Client)as Mail_client,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT platform) as platform,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rendering_engine)as rendering_engine,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category)as category
FROM Table
```

<kbd>[sqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36809c/7/0)</kbd>

result

```
MAIL_CLIENT                 PLATFORM      RENDERING_ENGINE      CATEGORY
-----------                 ---------     ----------------      --------
Android,Apple iPhone,Other  mobile,Other  Webkit,desktop,mobile read,deleted,skimmed
```

Answer (score 0):

try this , may this help you :

```
    SELECT maiL_client FROM `<tablename>` GROUP BY maiL_client
    union 
    SELECT plateform  FROM `<tablename>` GROUP BY plateform
    union
    SELECT rendering_engine  FROM `<tablename>` GROUP BY rendering_engine
    union
    SELECT category  FROM `<tablename>` GROUP BY category
```

Comment: This will select unique values for mail_client. But the other columns will have duplicates

Comment: yes , that is what he wants, if he wants each columns values unique then their will be irrelavent data comes in respective of each records...

Comment: I actually need unique values for each column. I need to use this data to create one drop down filter. So there is no point in repeating the data

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. Dont know works in MySQL or not.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TMP1.maiL_client, TMP2.platform, TMP3.rendering_engine, TMP4.category
FROM
( SELECT DISTINCT maiL_client  FROM TABLE_NAME) AS TMP1,
( SELECT DISTINCT platform FROM TABLE_NAME) AS TMP2,  
( SELECT DISTINCT rendering_engine FROM TABLE_NAME) AS TMP3,  
( SELECT DISTINCT category FROM TABLE_NAME) AS TMP4
```

Comment: These actually column names in same table. Not different tables

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...i'm not used to sql syntax..but hope you get my logic..

```
select A,B,C,D from
(select disitnct A,rownumber() as row_num from Table) as a outer join on a.row_num =b.row_num
(select disitnct B,rownumber() as row_num from Table) as b outer join on b.row_num =c.row_num
(select disitnct C,rownumber() as row_num from Table) as c outer join on c.row_num =d.row_num
(select disitnct D,rownumber() as row_num from Table) as d outer join on d.row_num =a.row_num
```

Answer (score -5):

```
SELECT DISTINCT maiL_client, platform, rendering_engine, category FROM <YourTable>
```

Comment: This is not working as it will duplicate the results